# Problem in setting date and time from java code

Tags: java, linux, datetime, serversocket

I am trying to set the date and time of a linux system from a remote system using Java. In order to do that I have created a server to accept time from the remote system as:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Set_date_n_time {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String date_time = new String();
        //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(7105);
        System.out.println("server started");
        while (true) {
            Socket sckt = s1.accept();
            InputStream input = sckt.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            date_time = reader.readLine(); 
            String command="sudo date -s "+"\""+date_time+"\"";
            Process p;
            try {
                p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                p.waitFor();
                System.out.println ("date set");
                p.destroy();
            } catch (Exception e) {} 
        }
}
}
```

and the remote system from which the time will be copied as:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fix_my_Date {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String addr_list=args[0];
        String[] hostList = readAddressList(addr_list);
        for(int i=0; i<hostList.length;i++) {
        setDate(hostList[i]);
        }
    }


    //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private static void setDate(String address) throws IOException {
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            Socket s = null;
            String date =new String();
            String time = new String();
            try {
                s = new Socket(address, 7105);
                System.out.println("connection to "+address+" done");
                Process p, p1;
                try {
                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date +%Y%m%d");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                            date = br.readLine();
                            br.close();
                    p.waitFor();
                    p.destroy();
                    p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("date +%H:%M:%S");
                    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
                            time = br1.readLine();
                            br1.close();
                    p1.waitFor();
                    p1.destroy();
                    PrintStream pr = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    pr.print(date+" "+time+"");
                    sc.close();
                    s.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Problem Setting date and time");
                } 


                //s.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't connect to: "+address+"");
                sc.close();

                //s.close();
            }

        }
        return;
    }


    private static String[] readAddressList(String addr_list) throws IOException {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(addr_list);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            lines.add(line);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        System.out.println("Loaded the host list");
        return lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);

    }

}
```

But the time is not being set by the server code. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Don’t swallow exceptions. An empty catch block is a no-no and could easily be hiding the answer to your question.

Comment: I will work on it, thank you

Comment: What is output? It may need more System.out.println to give more of an idea where the failure is.

Comment: Assuming you run on Linux, you have to make sure you can perform 'sudo' without entering the password. You did not specify how the server is launched, but for regular accounts, sudo will require password per session. Also, please log the executed command on the server, including the return code.

Comment: May I ask why you can't use NTP? (as your machines are both linux-based) There are also Java implementations of NTP clients/servers.

Comment: @bsaverino, the devices have no access to the internet. And for my work, around 1 sec of clock difference is acceptable.

Comment: @dash-o, the server is launched using sudo. And I could actually set the date and time separately using `date -s <date-only>` and `date +%T -s`. But couldn't do it at once.

Comment: Ok @se7en I understand. Just in case it is possible to tell/trick the NTP server to serve its local machine time to its clients. Maybe nothing much to learn here but who knows... https://serverfault.com/questions/806274/how-to-set-up-local-ntp-server-without-internet-access-on-ubuntu. At least there will be less to re-invent and as accuracy is not an issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to set the time on a VM? If that's the case, it may be set to synchronise to the host which overwrites your date -s command.

I could not get it to work (yet) with Runtime.exec(), but it works perfectly with ProcessBuilder. Here it is:

```
package set_date_n_time;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Set_date_n_time {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String date_time = new String();
        //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket s1 = new ServerSocket(7105);
        System.out.println("server started");
        while (true) {
            Socket sckt = s1.accept();
            InputStream input = sckt.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            date_time = reader.readLine();

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("date", "--set=" + date_time + "");
            final Process p = builder.start();
            p.waitFor();
            p.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you have to run as root and make sure you run

> sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd.service

or something similar to make sure the system does not override you date fixing.

Comment: Not VMs. They are two different linux machines!

Comment: ...and you ran "systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd.service" on the client machine?

Comment: I didn't run this (systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd.service). The devices are not connected to the internet. So, I didn't think about that. Let me try with it.

Comment: can you explain, why `-s` instead of `--set=` didn't work that i tried earlier?

Comment: -s worked but only if I did this:
String[] command = new String[]{"sudo", "date", "-s", date_time};

Comment: Always use separate arguments (like `"sudo", "date", "-s", date_time`), don't use `Runtime.exec(String)` which mangles the command.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake I, you, and lots of others make is also (besides the other helpful answers here) that you don't read Standard Output and Standard Error and if your command produces any output or error it blocks because there is no buffer that it can write to which you may observe with `strace`.

This could be fixed with an extra thread as described here: https://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

If you use sudo it might fail depending on the sudo settings if it doesn't allow sudo without a terminal (requiretty), see for more info e.g.: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1196451

Answer (score 1):

In case you need, or prefer, to use Runtime.exec() then (don't ask me why) just change:

```
String command = "sudo date -s " + "\"" + date_time + "\"";
```

to

```
String[] command = new String[]{"sudo", "date", "-s", date_time};
```

in class Set_date_n_time.

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()` at all; use `ProcessBuilder` (which `Runtime.exec()` itself calls in modern Java).

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```java
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

With this:

```java
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected exception", e);
}
```

As Ole V.V. said, the empty catch-block in your code is almost certainly discarding real failures you care about. I would guess that either `sudo` is rejecting the call or the command itself is malformed. The exception will tell you exactly what is going wrong.

*If* you discover there are exceptions being thrown that you really do want to ignore, handle them separately, but you should almost never `catch (Exception e)` and throw away the exception.

---

It's also a good idea to use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec()`. This is a more powerful and flexible API for interacting with sub-processes. In particular, *never* use `Runtime.exec(String)`; although it works for simple commands it is *not* a shell, and will fail in surprising ways for commands with special characters, like quotes or whitespace.

For example:

```java
p = new ProcessBuilder("sudo", "date", "-s", date_time).start();
```

Comment: Yes, later I tried with `exception e` but the control is not getting inside the catch block. I tried with process builder as well but no luck. Thanks for the shortcomings of `Runtime.exec()`